# How to use drools planner in netbeans

Tags: optaplanner, drools-planner

How to use drools planner in netbeans.

I'm beginner. I used drools but drools planner different for me.

I tried read the User Guide. but I still not understand.

Someone can help step by step, please.

My English is bad.

Answer (score 0):

[Drools Planner has been renamed to OptaPlanner.](http://www.optaplanner.org/community/droolsPlannerRenamed.html)

[These are the latest docs on how to set up the OptaPlanner examples in NetBeans.](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#runTheExamplesInAnIDE) If that doesn't suffice, google for using a existing **maven** project in **NetBeans**. There's nothing specific to such a setup for OptaPlanner examples, except - at the end - for the main class and working directory in the run configuration, of course.